# Comparing two values inserted into one class (Python3 )

Tags: python, class, comparison

Sorry if there is already something on here about this; I am just rather lost on this. Can someone help me finish my task here to help me understand? I do not understand how I am to compare the two class values (QBs).

TASK:

> Complete the rich comparisons methods. A quarterback is considered
>   greater than another only if that quarterback has both more wins and a
>   higher quarterback passer rating.

CODE:

```
class Quarterback:
        def __init__(self, yrds, tds, cmps, atts, ints, wins, ):
            self.wins = wins


            # Calculate quarterback passer rating
            self.rating = ((8.4*yrds) + (330*tds) + (100*cmps) - (200 * ints))/atts

        def __lt__(self, other):
            if self.wins < other.wins:


peyton = Quarterback(yrds=4700, atts=679, cmps=450, tds=33, ints=17, wins=10)
eli = Quarterback(yrds=4002, atts=539, cmps=339, tds=31, ints=25, wins=9)

if peyton > eli:
    print('Peyton is the better QB')
elif peyton < eli:
    print('Eli is the better QB')
else:
    print('It is not clear who the better QB is...')
```

Comment: Hint: *"More wins* `and` *higher quarterback passer rating"*.

Comment: A partial order then, rather than a total order. That would confuse some people.

Answer (score 0):

In your `__lt__` function, you can utilize this:

```
return (self.wins < other.wins) and (self.rating < other.rating)
```

This returns:

```
`Peyton is the better QB`
```

The return function is checking *both* conditions specified - higher rating AND more wins

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is ".other" a built in function?

Comment: No. You are passing it as part of the `__lt__` function.

Comment: ...it's a parameter of the method. Did you even read the boilerplate you were provided with?

Comment: Okay, I see now. I didn't comprehend how it was passing both throw before running the comparison. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Info given to solve:

Rich comparisons for a quarterback class.
Complete the **gt** method. A quarterback is considered greater than another
only if that quarterback has more wins and a higher quarterback passer rating.

Once **gt** is complete, compare Tom Brady's 2007 stats as well
(4,806 yards; 50 touchdowns; 398 completions; 578 attempts; 8 interceptions; 16 wins).

(A few additions were needed to make the code below complete, I commented my changes below.)

```
class Quarterback:
    def __init__(self, yrds, tds, cmps, atts, ints, wins):
        self.wins = wins
        # Calculate quarterback passer rating (NCAA)
        self.rating = ((8.4 *yrds) + (33.0 *tds) + (10.0 *cmps) - (200 * ints) ) /atts

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if (self.rating < other.rating) or (self.wins < other.wins):
            return True
        return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if (self.rating > other.rating) and (self.wins > other.wins):
            return True
        return False  # modified the statements in this rich comparison^


peyton = Quarterback(yrds=4700, atts=679, cmps=450, tds=33, ints=17, wins=10)
eli = Quarterback(yrds=4002, atts=539, cmps=339, tds=31, ints=25, wins=9)
tom = Quarterback(yrds=4806, atts=578, cmps=398, tds=50, ints=8, wins=16)  # what i added

if peyton > tom and peyton > eli:  # made the conditions include tom in every > comparison.
    print('Peyton is the better QB')
elif eli > peyton and eli > tom:
    print('Eli is the better QB')
elif tom > eli and tom > peyton:
    print('Tom is the better QB')  # added this print statement

else:
    print('It is not clear who the better QB is...')
```